# Thread safe Hash Map?

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, java.util.concurrent

I am writing an application which will return a HashMap to user. User will get reference to this MAP.
On the backend, I will be running some threads which will update the Map.

**What I have done so far?**

---

I have made all the backend threads so share a common channel to update the MAP. So at backend I am sure that concurrent write operation will not be an issue.

---

**Issues I am having**

---

1. If user tries to update the MAP and simultaneously MAP is being updated at backend --> Concurrent write operation problem.
2. If use tries to read something from MAP and simultaneously MAP is being updated at backend --> concurrent READ and WRITE Operation problem.

Untill now I have not face any such issue, but i m afraid that i may face in future. Please give sugesstions.

I am using `ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>.`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You are on the right track using [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).  For each point:

1. Check out the methods [`putIfAbsent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent(K%2C%20V)) and [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#replace(K%2C%20V)) both are threadsafe and combine checking current state of hashmap and updating it into one atomic operation.
2. The [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)) method is not synchronized internally but will return the most recent value for the specified key available to it (check the [ConcurrentHashMap class Javadoc for discussion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)).

The benefit of `ConcurrentHashMap` over something like [`Collections.synchronizedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)) is the combined methods like `putIfAbsent` which provide traditional Map `get` and `put` logic in an internally synchronized way.  Use these methods and *do not* try to provide your own custom synchronization over `ConcurrentHashMap` as it will not work.  The `java.util.concurrent` collections are internally synchronized and other threads will not respond to attempts at synchronizing the object (e.g. `synchronize(myConcurrentHashMap){}` will not block other threads).

Comment: How does a ConcurrentHashMap compare to a ConcurrentSkipListMap?

Answer (score 8):

Side Note:

You might want to look into the lock free hash table implementation by Cliff Click, it's part of the [Highly Scalable Java](http://sourceforge.net/projects/high-scale-lib/) library

(Here's a [Google Talk](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=2139967204534450862) by Cliff Click about this lock free hash.)

Answer (score 1):

ConcurrentHashMap was designed and implemented to avoid any issues with the scenarios you describe. You have nothing to worry about.

> A hash table supporting full
>   concurrency of retrievals and
>   adjustable expected concurrency for
>   updates.updates.

[javadoc of ConcurrentHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)