# Jmeter : How to initialize map once and share it for all threads in a thread group

Tags: jmeter

I am having one thread groups in my **j-meter test plan** and I want to pre-initialize  two map. like

```
java.util.HashMap myMap1 = new java.util.HashMap();
myMap1.put("foo1","bar1");
myMap1.put("foo2","bar2");

java.util.HashMap myMap2 = new java.util.HashMap();
myMap2.put("mykey",myMap1);
```

and I have to use it for different threads.Can anyone help me to sort out this problem?

Comment: make it `synchronized` or use `concurrentHashMap`

Comment: You want a threadsafe map, see:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222512/thread-safe-hash-map

Comment: @AstraBear thanx but i am talking about jmeter thread group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what test element you're using for scripting there could be 2 options:

1. If you use [Beanshell Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) - the easiest option is using [bsh.shared](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables) namespace as

   In first thread group:

   ```
   Map myMap1 = new HashMap();
   myMap1.put("foo","bar");
   bsh.shared.myMap = myMap1;
   ```

   In second thread group:

   ```
   Map myMap1 = bsh.shared.myMap;
   log.info(myMap1.get("foo"));
   ```
2. More "generic" way is using JMeter Properties. A shorthand to current instance of JMeter Properties is available as `props` in any script-enabled test element (JSR223 Sampler, BSF Sampler, etc.) and it is basically an instance of [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class hence it has put() method which accepts arbitrary Java Object as value. So

   In first thread group:

   ```
   Map myMap1 = new HashMap();
   myMap1.put("foo","bar");
   props.put("myMap", myMap1);
   ```

   In second thread group:

   ```
   Map myMap1 = props.get("myMap");
   log.info(myMap1.get("foo"));
   ```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to share such stuff among multiple threads then go Singleton Object. Since single object will be shared among all the threads therefore all the threads will see the same change.

For more explanation follow the below snippet :-

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SingletonMap {
    private  HashMap myMap1 = null;
    private  HashMap myMap2 = null;
    private static volatile SingletonMap singletonMapObj = null;

    private SingletonMap(){
        myMap1 = new HashMap();
        myMap2 = new HashMap();

        myMap1.put("foo1","bar1");
        myMap1.put("foo2","bar2");

        myMap2.put("mykey",myMap1);
    }

    public static SingletonMap getSingletonMap(){
        if(singletonMapObj == null){
            new SingletonMap();
        }

        return singletonMapObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: no i am talking about how i can acheive in jmeter(load testing tool) configuration.