# What happens when two threads try to modify/ access the same key in Concurrent HashMap?

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I read about hashMap and how it is different from hashtable. Like in hashtable the complete object gets locked while in case of concurrent hashmap only a part of it is locked. My question is what happens when two threads try to access the same value correspoding to a key at the samme time.

Lets say

```
 Map mp = new ConcurrentHashMap(); 
 mp.put(1, "Hello");
```

Thread 1: trying to read mp.get(1).

Thread 2: trying to write/modify into it mp.put(1, "Hi").

so What value does thread 1 gets to read?

Edit: I meant ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: Hello, or Hi, depending on the ordering of the operations (assuming the map is a ConcurrentHashMap, not a HashMap).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222512/thread-safe-hash-map

Comment: Are you asking about a `java.util.HashMap` used concurrently, or about a `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: Sorry I meant concurrentHashMap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What value does thread 1 gets to read?

It will read two possible values, either

- it gets `null` as the value hasn't been set yet.
- it get the value Thread 2 set.

This might not sound like a great deal but you should note that with `HashMap` it is possible to go into an infinite loop and never return, which is bad.

Where `ConcurrentHashMap` is really useful is in operations like `putIfAbsent` For passing work between threads, a Queue is much better choice.

```
ConcurrentMap<Integer, BlockingQueue<String>> map = ...
```

Thread 1

```
String value = map.putIfAbsent(1, k -> new BlockingQueue<>()).take();
```

Thread 2

```
map.putIfAbsent(1, k -> new BlockingQueue<>()).offer("Hi");
```

In this case, Thread 1 will block until Thread 2 has added a value.  Note: this value is only available once.